# Deleting from arrays with object by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a object like this

```
myArray = [
              { name: "1",
                age: "20"
               },         
              { name: "6",
                age: "20"
               },  
              { name: "2",
                age: "20"
               },  
             ];

  anotherArray = [2,1,3,4,5,6];
```

Basically I am trying to find if match a exists, if it does then delete it from `myArray`

```
    for(var i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++) {
      var searchTerm = myArray[i].name;
      for (var j = 0; j < anotherArray.length; j++) {
      if (myArray[i].name === anotherArray[j]) {
        // Not exactly sure how the deletion will work with array.splice
        len--;
        break;
    }
   }
  }
```

For some reason it does not seem to be working as expected.

The end result should be this

```
   myArray = [         
              { name: "6",
                age: "20"
               } 
             ];
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: Note that if you splice out the current member, you need to decrement the counter and shorten the limit to iterate over since length will be shorter too. Simpler to iterate in reverse so those aren't issues.

Comment: Or use a combo of `filter` and `indexOf`, something like `arr1.filter(function(x){return ~arr2.indexOf(x.name)}`

Comment: @elclanrs Oh the ~readability! =) (I like the solution, though)

Comment: @elclanrs— *indexOf* uses `===` so `"1" !== 1`. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues. There is a trailing comma in the *myArray* array literal that is incorrectly treated as an elision in IE, so the array has a length that is too long. Also, *anotherArray* includes all the members of *myArray*, so if the function works, it removes all of them.

You can use *splice* to remove members from an array. It affects the length and in an incrementing loop means you'll skip the next member if you don't modify the counter. The usual strategy is to use a decrementing loop to avoid those issues.

Lastly, the "name" property is a string but the values in *anotherArray* are numbers, which might mess with the comparison.

```
myArray = [
              { name: "1",
                age: "20"
               },         
              { name: "6",
                age: "20"
               },  
              { name: "2",
                age: "20"
               }                   // trailing comma removed
             ];

  anotherArray = [2,1,3,4,5];  // 6 removed so one member remains


for (var i=myArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  // Convert name to a number since indexOf uses ===
  if (anotherArray.indexOf(+myArray[i].name) != -1) {
    myArray.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

console.log(myArray[0].name);
```

A polyfill for *indexOf* can be found at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill).

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing two diferent things (types) as myArray[i].name is a String Object and anotherArray[j] is a Number Object. You should convert one of them OR use the equality operator ("=="), instead of strict equality operator("==="). For further reference see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators)

Even though it might be viewed as poor code you can delete using the delete keyword (as remembered by @RobG, it will not change the length, leaving a empty reference):

```
...
if (myArray[i].name === anotherArray[j]) {
    delete myArray[i];
...
```

[Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) should do it:

```
myArray.filter(function(i) { return Array.prototype.indexOf([2,1,3,4,5,6], i.name) })
```

But the result will include the objects with name in [1,2,6]

Comment: Nasty, that leaves no member at index 2 (i.e. `[{...}, , {...}]`) so length is still 3.

Comment: @RobG No it does not. What browser you're using?

Comment: Absolutely it does, the [delete operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.1) does not do anything special (like array methods do) such as adjust the length of the array or the index of other members.

Comment: Ow sorry... I though you were talking about the other... sure about the delete you're right... my bad... ;P

Comment: Whether it's an issue or not depends on the robustness of other code. Most assume compact arrays so probably best not to feed them sparse. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You've got several things going on here that are going to give you trouble. For one thing, using the string equality operator `===` will prevent any kind of type coercion from being done, meaning that `"1"` and `1` will not be equal. If you wish to perform a type conversion, you should use the `==` equality operator:

```
"1" === 1;
=> false

"1" == 1;
=> true
```

Additionally, it seems to me that you are over complicating things with this method. If you wish to remove all objects from your array whose name is contained in `anotherArray`, you should use the standard `Array.prototype.filter` method to produce the array you want:

```
var myArray = [{name: "1", age: "20"}, 
               {name: "6", age: "20"}, 
               {name: "2", age: "20"}],
    anotherArray = [2,1,3,4,5,6];

myArray = myArray.filter(function(e) {
 return (a.indexOf(e.name|0) < 0)   // note: e.name|0 will convert the string 
});                                 // value of e.name to an integer
=> [];
```

A couple things to note about the code you posted:

1. Because `anotherArray` is declared without a preceding `var` and is not part of a comma-separated `var` statement, it will be instantiated as a *global* variable. This behavior is highly undesirable and can result in some very strange errors in your code.
2. You stated that you expect the result of your deletion to result in the following array:

   `myArray = [{name: "6", age: "20"}]`

   however, notice that `6` is an element in `anotherArray` and therefore your resulting array should actually be empty.

Comment: Note that *name* is a string but the values in *anotherArray* are numbers so they will not match using *indexOf*.

Comment: @RobG you are correct, however the expression `e.name|0` uses the bitwise OR to convert `e.name` to an integer. It's a very similar operation to your use of the unary `+`

Comment: Ah yes, missed that. Might have seen `+e.name` though. :-)